# const to non-const c++

Tags: c++, constants

is this possible:

changing a constant variable to non-constant

I am making a whole new string class and my constructor looks like this

```
LString(const char string1[]) {/* whatever I do */}
```

I wouldn't put the const keyword but that is the only way I can get strings like

```
LString ls = "a string";
```

I will have a lot of functions to modify this string

even though I make a copy of this string I still cannot convert const to non const

is it possible

if not, can anyone think of a loophole

ok so some people were saying that there is no problem, well here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
class LString
{
public:
LString(const char string1[]){
char s1[250] = {string1};
cout << "you constructed LString with a const string as a parameter";
}

};
```

this comes up with the following errors

> file.cpp: In constructor 'LString::LString(const char*)':
>
> file.cpp:7:24: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char'

if this makes a difference I am using the mingw compiler without an IDE

I am compiling through the command prompt

I think thats all the info you might need

tell me if you need anymore

Comment: I can't really see who put a (-1) in your question, which is too bad and I'm sorry; Whoever did it missed the point of SO, which is to enable people to make questions about programming and, as far as I'm concerned, your question fits perfectly.

Comment: @Bruno: agreed. +1 to this question, it's a good one.

Comment: You can't modify a string literal. You need to make a copy or rethink what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your constructor is fine - the input should be const.

The copy can be non-const, no problem.

```
#include <string.h>
class A {
  public:
  A(const char* string)
    : a(strdup(string))
  {}
  char* a;
};
```

Here I'm using strdup to make a copy.  What are you using?

Comment: Please free() the copied string in the destructor or use std::string. Otherwise this oversimplified example leaks memory.

Comment: Use a `std::string const &` param and `std::string` member and the memory management is done for you.

Comment: @lothar true, but I was trying to address the problem, not memory management.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the compiler thinks you're trying to change the string you're assigning from. Since it can't be changed that's why it's complaining. Did you make a copy of the string to make changes to?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the problem. Keep the constructor signature as it is, but make the internal variable non-const and copy it over. Copy it at the start of the func and then work with that variable instead.